# Output/Print variable, in code, in if statement

Tags: vba, if-statement

I am trying to achieve the following:
The user is shown an excel spread sheet with a list of assumption which they can change.

```
Title       |     Value        |
Input01     |       10         |  =
Input02     |       2          |  >=
Input03     |       800        |  >=
Input04     |       4          |  >=
Input05     |       2          |  <=
```

There is an `If .. Then` Statement that pulls in data if the assumption are met. However if an assumption is blanc, it should not be included in the `If .. Then` Statement.

```
If x = Input01Value And y >= Input02Value _
And z >= Input03Value And a >= Input04Value _
And b <= Input05Value Then
```

User ommits Input03

```
If x = Input01Value And y >= Input02Value _
And a >= Input04Value And b <= Input05Value Then
```

Now I could check to see if each value exist, and then follow it  by another `If` statement with the appropriate variables. But this seems a bit redundant.

I was wondering if something like the following is possible:

```
Input 01 = ""
If Input01Value != "" Then Input01 = "x = " & Input01Value
'Then use join or something similar to join all of them ..
```

And Then use this `Input01` directly in the `If .. Then` statement. This way when a variable is empty the `And ..` are not included and the `If` statement will not fail.
Eg. (I know this doesn't work, just illustrating the scenario)

```
VBA: If Input01 Then
Result while compiling: If x = Input01Value Then
```

Please Note, I know I could do something like the following:
`If Boolean And Variable2 > 4 Then` and then have `Boolean` and `Variable2` populate with a value in the cell, however the issue with this is that if the user, for example, decides to omit the `Variable2` (which is reasonable) it will fail. eg. `If (Boolean = True) And > 4 Then`.

Hope my question is clear, thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no need to embed logic in code like that: you should write the `If` test to use the value of `CoverageRatioInput` directly.

Comment: But then it will fail if `CoverageRatioInput` has no value, right?

Comment: Then you first test if it has a value...  All of the same logic required to write code to perform a test can be expressed directly in the test.

Comment: But then if I have more than one variable, it will lead to a mess of spaghetti code. If I would have 5 variables it will result in 120 different statements.. that seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Handling a bunch of different outcomes doesn't necessarily require an equivalent number of separate tests. You replace your "generic test code writing" code with "testing" code. Your example code tests to see if a number is an integer between 1 and a user-supplied number: you can write a test that does that directly.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have reworded my question. The issue is not the individual test (I know it is not very efficient), it is the combination (or ommitions) of restriction of a test based on given inputs.

Comment: You would loop through the rows of parameters from the worksheet, testing each row in turn (using something along the lines of what @charlespwd posted). As soon as the function returns false you end the tests and the overall result is false. If your input is suitable you can use something like `bResult=Application.Evaluate(testValue & inputOperator & inputValue)`

Answer (score 1):

What about using a function which operates on a select case depending on a string operator and two values?

```
Function conditionalString(condition As String, x As Variant, y As Variant) As Boolean
Select Case condition
    Case "="
        If (x = y) Then
            conditionalString = True
        Else
            conditionalString = False
        End If
        Exit Function
    Case ">="
        conditionalString = (x >= y)
        Exit Function
    Case "<="
        conditionalString = (x <= y)
        Exit Function
    Case ">"
        conditionalString = (x > y)
        Exit Function
    Case "<"
        conditionalString = (x < y)
        Exit Function
    Case Else
        conditionalString = False
End Select
End Function
```

You could then just have another function, say "check if value isn't blank" before calling all assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, you can use something like this to test each row of input.

```
Function TestIt(testValue,inputOperator,inputValue) As Boolean
    If Len(inputValue)=0 Then
        TestIt=True 'ignore this test: no value supplied
    Else
        TestIt=Application.Evaluate(testValue & inputOperator & inputValue)
    End If
End function
```